# Interpret variance analysis in R

Tags: r, anova

I would appreciate some help interpreting and inferring outputs from `aov()` in R, and understand what the next step is in the analysis.

**Background**: I am working with `AOV()` in R and I will do an analysis of variance where the main purpose of the study is to investigate the influence of storage conditions on the flavour of apples, The task is to find out about influential factors and describe their influence. The storage conditions that I have are:

1. storage time in a container;
2. the oxygen content of the container;
3. post-storage period outside the container

Which means that immediately after harvest the apples were transferred to one of four containers where they are stored in different oxygen environments. Two storage periods were tested, of 50 days and 100 days, and four different oxygen environments. After these storage periods, apples were sampled from the containers and allowed to ripen in normal atmosphere during a post-storage period at six different time intervals. The apple flavor has then been reported on a scale of 1-5. So we thus appear to have a three-way ANOVA with 2x4x6 levels for conditions 1-3.

**My understanding**: I looked at a step-by-step guide online as well as using tasks in the course literature and found that they started by performing `aov()` on the data and checked his summary. So I did this and got the following output:

```
summary(aov(response ~ factor(storage) + factor(poststorage) + factor(oxygen)))

Output:
                 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
factor(storage)   1  0.613   0.613   1.395    0.245    
factor(ripening)  5  1.745   0.349   0.794    0.561    
factor(oxygen)    3 14.585   4.862  11.065 2.32e-05 ***
Residuals        38 16.696   0.439
```

and here I interpret that the only significant factor is the oxygen, since it it the only one with a p-value lower than 0.05, and that we cannot reject the null hypothesis that storage and post storage does not affect the response?

I also looked at the interactions between oxygen, storage and post storage and found the following:

```
summary(aov(response ~ (factor(storage) + factor(ripening) + factor(oxygen))^2))

output:
                                 Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
factor(storage)                   1  0.613   0.613   1.833 0.195806    
factor(ripening)                  5  1.745   0.349   1.044 0.428348    
factor(oxygen)                    3 14.585   4.862  14.539 0.000104 ***
factor(storage):factor(ripening)  5  0.644   0.129   0.385 0.851185    
factor(storage):factor(oxygen)    3  1.299   0.433   1.295 0.312621    
factor(ripening):factor(oxygen)  15  9.738   0.649   1.941 0.105203    
Residuals                        15  5.016   0.334                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

and from this output table I found that the ´storage:ripening´, ´storage:oxygen´ and ´ripening:oxygen´ variables has a low sum-of-squares value and a high p-value, which means there is not much variation that can be explained by the interaction between fertilizer and planting density. However, ´storage:oxygen:ripening´ is missing
and this I cannot explain. But my guess is that it could be because they interact?

**Question**: If I have made a correct interpretation of my summaries; why is ‘storage:oxygen:ripening’ missing when I look for interactions,
is it because they interact? If this is correct, is this enough information to investigate the influence of storage conditions on the flavour of apples
or should one do one-sided analyzes for all of the storage conditions where I check the constituent groups in each one of them more?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Why I can't find the interaction for ´storage:oxygen:ripening´, the F-and p-values doesn't emerge:

````
aov(response ~ (factor(storage) + factor(poststorage) + factor(oxygen))^3)

output:
factor(storage)                                  1  0.613   0.613
factor(ripening)                                 5  1.745   0.349
factor(oxygen)                                   3 14.585   4.862
factor(storage):factor(ripening)                 5  0.644   0.129
factor(storage):factor(oxygen)                   3  1.299   0.433
factor(ripening):factor(oxygen)                 15  9.738   0.649
factor(storage):factor(ripening):factor(oxygen) 15  5.016   0.334
```
````

Comment: Your interpretation is ok.  `(a+b+c)^2` only gives main effects and pairs.  Try `(a+b+c)^3`  get three level interactions too or `a*b*c` to get all interactions which in this case is the same.

Comment: With ok, do you mean that it is something that I miss except for only testing `(a+b+c)^2`. And I tried for a three level interactions too but then the F-and p-values doesn't emerge. I updated my question with this output.

Comment: You may not have enough data/degrees of freedom to allow testing with three level interactions.